# Hiding images of Products that have multiple images only (mainly colors)

Tags: jquery

I got a page of Products. Some products have multiple images (colors). I want to hide all of them accept the first image.

HTML

```
      <li class="prod">
          <img src="image/something.jpg"  /> 
        <h1>Spalding Women's Running Pant</h1>
      </li>
      <li class="prod">
          <img src="image/something.jpg"  /> 
          <img src="image/something2.jpg" />
          <img src="iimage/something.jpg3"/> 
        <h1>Spalding Women's Running Shorts</h1>
      </li>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and this way is pretty much similar :

jQuery:

```
$('.prod').find('img:first').show();
```

css:

```
.prod img {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I like this one. Its cleaner rather than doing a double filter which don't work well.

Comment: Thanks man! I tried this with .each() but this seems alot better.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.prod').find('img').not(':first-child').hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WM633/).

Working in Chromium 12/Ubuntu 11.04.

---

**Edited** with regard to the comments from @kingjiv (short version: he's absolutely right):

> This is fine as long as no other content ends up before the first image tag. Otherwise that other content (be it a span or whatever) is the first child which would then hide all images in that li...I think `.find('img:not(:first)')` would solve that.

```
$('.prod').find('img:not(:first)').hide();
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WM633/1/).

---

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Comment: This is fine as long as no other content ends up before the first image tag.  Otherwise that other content (be it a span or whatever) is the first child which would then hide all images in that `li`

Comment: There is more code in the li.prod tag. I removed some code to make this easier, but its the only img tag in the wrapper.